# How to create a BitmapFont that has multiple .TGA files in it

Tags: java, android, bitmap, libgdx

looking at the [LibGDX BitmapFont documentation](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html) I don't see that there is a way for me to add multiple .tga files to the BitmapFont. This only gives me troubles when the Font size is greater than ~42 so it has to create another .tga file. I'm using [BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) for turning my .ttf file to a Bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Font generator to create BitmapFonts at runtime at the right sizes. You can create those at different fontsizes and it shouldnt have that problem.

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2300 take a look at this it may help. There are severel tutorials how to use it.

If you dont want to use this take a look at the Wiki:

[generate Fonts](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts)